# AppWidget refresh 12 times

Tags: java, android, widget

I have code:

```
    int i = 0;
    while(true){
    i++;

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1,  "" +  i );
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code refresh my widget, but only 12 times. When "i" reaches 12  nothing happens.
How to fix it?

Comment: What you want exactly ? infinity times for refresh?

Answer (score 0):

AppWidgetProvider class extends BroadCastReciever , and it is not correct to have the while(true) loop in the reciever class.

If you want to refresh the widget at an interval of every 1 second then provide the information in the android:updatePeriodMillis="1000" in the app widget xml file which is placed at res/xml/ folder in your project.

Thanks!
Bhushan